# Two add/edit node forms: How to let the user choose

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I have created a module where I use node_form_alter to change the add/edit form of a certain datatype. I want the user to be able to choose between two altered versions of the form. Preferably I want to have a page where they can click either of two links "Formtype 1" or "Formtype 2" and depending on which they click be taken to the node add/edit form with appropriate alterations. Any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: This is pretty specific to Drupal - you may be better off at a Drupal forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use two links like:

1. `node/add/node_type/f1`
2. `node/add/node_type/f2`

The last part of the path will be ignored by drupal, but in node_form_alter you can access every part of the url part with the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function.